# PushSharp to work with Google Play Services

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, pushsharp

I have installed PushSharp for a while on our server and since GCM is deprecated, I wanted to know if somebody has already implemented Google Play Services with this package and what has to be done in the PushSharp code to support Google Play Services.

Comment: What do you mean by GCM is deprecated? I think `PushSharp` is deprecated. and GCM not, take look at the official doc [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) with the latest Google play services updated.

Comment: If you are an Android developer you should probably know that the GCM library is deprecated and the Google Play Services has to be used instead. Since PushSharp, despite what you think, is an excellent product, I just wanted to know if there is something to change in the Pushsharp package in order to support Google Play Services or if GCM is just part of it and nothing has changed in the protocol.